# At what approximate time will the temperature first reach $95$ degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I am studying for the pre-calculus CLEP exam and I have come across a question where I keep getting a different answer from the textbook I am using. I am wondering if my answer is incorrect or the textbook. Here is the question:

The June temperature of a central Texas town can be modeled by:

> $$T(t) = 30\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}t\right) + 68$$

where $t$ is the time in hours after noon. At what approximate time will the temperature first reach $95$ degrees?

[Here](https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=27%2F30%3Dsin(PI%2F12)t) is what my answer looked like and it came out to be about 3:48 PM.

Comment: What answer did you get and how did you derive it?

Comment: I got 3.477333, or 3:48 PM. I got this by simplifying the equation to look like this: https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=27%2F30%3Dsin(PI%2F12)t

Comment: Yes, please post your (attempted) solution. You'll get a more constructive, helpful response that way, as we can tell what (if anything) you did wrong.

Comment: OK, it would be better to include that in the actual post. Here's your mistake. You said that $\sin(ct) = (\sin c)\cdot t$. You can't ungroup the $c$ and $t$. You need to solve $\frac{9}{10} = \sin (\frac\pi{12}t)$ by using the arcsin key (or inverse function key) on your calculator.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I did not realize this. I am trying to teach myself calculus and I still have a lot more to learn! :)

Comment: One other error:  Do not forget to convert fractional hours into minutes.  You converted $0.477333~\text{h}$ into $48$ minutes when it should have been $0.477333~\text{h} \cdot 60~\frac{\text{min}}{\text{h}} \approx 29~\text{min}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Good catch, I totally missed that!